# Fastlane: Running commit version bump in a project with multiple targets and cocoa pods gives error of uncommitted files

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

So I am using Fastlane. Now everything was smooth until we had only 1 target, now I have about 6 targets. 
Also, another change now is that I use cocoapods now.

when my Fastlane lane runs. And it tries to perform commit_version_bump action.

I get the following error.

```
[!] Found unexpected uncommitted changes in the working directory. Expected these files to 
have changed: 
Target1.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Target1/Resources/Target1-Info.plist
Target2/Resources/Target2-Info.plist
Target2/Target2-Info.plist
Target3/Target3-Info.plist
Target4/Target4-Info.plist
Target6/Target6-Info.plist.
But found these actual changes: 
.... some files from project....
Externals/Down/
Externals/FastImageCache/
Make sure you have cleaned up the build artifacts and 
are only left with the changed version files at this stage in your lane, and don't touch the 
working directory while your lane is running. You can also use the :force option to bypass this 
check, and always commit a version bump regardless of the state of the working directory.
```

Can someone help. Your time is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add your Fastlane config? Also, those files that were not expected, were generated by your lane or you started with a dirty git status?

Comment: I ll add my fastlane config, but the files were generated by the lane. I never started with a dirty git status. Also, as a safeguard to this particular issue, I ran clean_build_artifacts before commit-version-bump.

Comment: For me `sudo bundle update` was what was needed.

Comment: I tried `ignore` option of `commit_version_bump` but it doesn't work. It will produce  unexpected changes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the safest way to do so, but gets the job done:

```
commit_version_bump(
      ...
      force: true
)
```